# Java inheritance and super method

Tags: java

I have an object of  StatCalc which uses getMethods to display in a driver class under main methods. However instead of modyfing StatCalc which has sourcecode.  getAvg, getSum, getCount etc...

I have another class which purely getmin() and getmax()

```
public class StatCalcWithMinMax extends StatCalc {

private double max = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;  // Largest item seen.
private double min = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;  // Smallest item seen.

public void enter(double num) {
      // Add the number to the dataset.
   super.enter(num);  // Call the enter method from the StatCalc class.
   if (num > max)  // Then do the extra processing for min and max.
      max = num;
   if (num < min)
      min = num;
}

public double getMin() {
     // Return the smallest item that has been entered.
     // Value will be infinity if no items have been entered.
   return min;
}

public double getMax() {
     // Return the largest item that has been entered.
     // Value will be -infinity if no items have been entered.
   return max;
}

 }
```

so the main is this however i can't access getMix and getmax from class above.

```
public class driver {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    StatCalc calc; // Object to be used to process the data.
    calc = new StatCalc();
    boolean isZero = false;

    while (isZero != true) {
        Scanner inputer = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numEntered = inputer.nextInt();
        if (numEntered == 0) {
            //isZero = true;
            break;
        }

        calc.enter(numEntered);

    }

    System.out.println("The numbers entered were: "+ calc.getCount());
    System.out.println("The mean of the numbers entered:" + calc.getMean());
    System.out.println("The Standard deviation of the numbers entered: "+ calc.getStandardDeviation());
//  System.out.println("The minimum number encountered was: "+ calc.getMin());
//  System.out.println("The maximum number encountered was: "+ calc.getMax());


}
```

}

Comment: in your StatCalc, does it contain method `getMin()` and `getMax()`?

Comment: yes, because calc is an instance of `StatCalc`, it does not have a min and max value.

Comment: just like `String extends Object`, it does not mean that an instance of `Object` has a `getBytes` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are still using

```
 StatCalc calc; // Object to be used to process the data.
```

change to

```
 StatCalcWithMinMax calc; // Object to be used to process the data.
 calc = new StatCalcWithMinMax ();
```

Comment: aahhhh so does this mean all the methods from StatCalc class can be used along with StatCalcWithMinMax methods?  Power of inheritance?

Comment: got it, i probably read over inheritance like a million times. I finally understand it. Learn to code, by coding. Thanks